# Missing select keyword in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting this error

> SQL Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
>   00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"`

when I am trying to insert like this

```
create table certf
(
    certificate_id integer primary key,
    certificate_name varchar(100) not null,
    certificate_content varchar(300) not null
);

insert into certf (&certificate_id, &certificate_name, &certificate_content);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If those are supposed to be values you're providing as substitution values, then you're missing the `values` keyword:

```
insert into certf values (&certificate_id,&certificate_name,&certificate_content);
```

But you need the string values to be in quotes:

```
insert into certf values (&certificate_id,'&certificate_name','&certificate_content');
```

and you should supply the column names too:

```
insert into certf (certificate_id,certificate_name,certificate_content)
values (&certificate_id,'&certificate_name','&certificate_content');
```

---

With you current code the parser is seeing that first list of - possible, but actually invalid in this case - identifiers, i.e column names; because it hasn't seen that `values` keyword yet. It's treated as something like:

```
insert into certf (42,some_name,some_content);
```

And having done that, and when it still doesn't see a `values` keyword or values list, it's expecting this to be an `insert ... select` construct instead. You *could* do it that way:

```
insert into certf (certificate_id,certificate_name,certificate_content)
select &certificate_id,'&certificate_name','&certificate_content' from dual;
```

But you aren't doing that. So it doesn't see the `select` either, and it throws the error you see.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing `values` actually:

```
insert into certf (certificate_id, certificate_name, certificate_content)
    values (&certificate_id, &certificate_name, &certificate_content);
```

Notice that I also added the column list to the `insert`.  This is a best practice.

Comment: You could explain the error-message "values(..) or a select.. is needed". Because of the missing values a select is expected.